# How to update .NET Core on Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have my Azure Web App configured to deploy from a local git repository - I just push my changes to the Web App git repo and it builds and deploys the site.

I just updated to my ASP .NET Core site to: `"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003133"`, previously it was 003131 which worked no problems.

I now get the response when doing the git push:

> remote: GETSDKTOOLINGINFO : error : The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003133 which is not installed or cannot be found under the path D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet. These components are required to build and run this project. Download the version of .NET Core SDK specified in global.json or update the SDK version in global.json to the version that is installed.

I would prefer to update the .NET Core version on my Web App than downgrade, but how?

In case you are wonder how I have 3133 already: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/801

Comment: Did you try switching to self-contained apps rather than portable app? learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can not update the dotnet version on Azure.  Currently the version of dotnet that is running is 003131. So you still have to use the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

How are you building your release package?

I had this yesterday using a VSTS build process, when using the 'Visual Studio' build task it will fail with this error currently - changing your process to use the "CMD line" build task and "dotnet publish" allows the build to complete successfully.